# Free software to synchronize two sql server databases

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a free software that can:

1. Compare two MS Sql Server databases (Both schema & data)
2. Also provide a method to synchronize the databases.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I am not looking for any mirroring solution etc. Not a server solution. Just a simple desktop app that can show be a differences between two sql server databases and generate some script to make the schema/db in sync.

Comment: Please provide more information, otherwise you get useless answers such as mirroring. Did you look into replication?

Comment: When I saw the question in the unanswered list, I immediately thought "why don't they use log shipping or mirroring?"  More info is definitely needed like TomTom said, for all anyone knows, either of those could be viable solutions depending on what is needed... although I have a feeling ozamora is on the right track here.

Answer (score 2):

To sync up data, that is a tough find if you dont wan to pay. OpenDBDiff can do schema for free